# Laravel Eloquent: cherry pick custom attributes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I'm using an API to retrieve my objects in JSON. I have a model which has a lot of computing-intensive custom attributes (for example, sums from other tables in the database). On some pages, I'd like to load a *specific* set of custom attributes.

If they were relationships, I could use Model::with().

I'm looking for a way to "eager load" my custom attributes.
For performance reasons, I don't want to add them to the model's $append list.

Comment: You mean you want to use laravel relationships?

Comment: Actually, I don't think I can : the attribute I want to retreive is a single field (sum), not a Model. I don't need the info on every page using the model, so I'm looking for a way to cherry-pick which ones I append in the json. For example, i'd like to ... append an attribute name in the model's $apprend array

Comment: What about using a query string with what you want to load? `&load=posts,comments` Or pass them in the data provided in the json request?